# Can a STM32 microcontroller board be connected to AWS IoT core without its discovery kit?

Tags: amazon-web-services, stm32, aws-iot, aws-iot-core, stm32f1

I was searching in the net about connection between STM32 microcontroller and AWS IoT core, didnt come across any. I cam across articles where the discovery board of STM32 is used to connect to AWS IoT core. But I want a simple way to connect the STM32 microcontroller to AWS IoT core with the help of WiFi module (since STM32 microcontroller boards dont usually have WiFi modules)

I tried searching as I have already told but didnt come any resources related to what I was searching. I was specifically looking for resources related to STM32F1 series.

Answer (score 0):

You need internet connectivity to be able to connect to aws iot. That could be wireless or ethernet. STM32f4 could work with ethernet.
Or, you move to ESP32.

What I’ve done in the past is to connect a stm32L1 to esp8266 over spi.

Answer (score 0):

AWS provides a tutorial on how to use the IoT Device SDK for Embedded C - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-embedded-c-sdk.html

They also provide sample apps specifically ported for STM32 (STM32L4 discovery board - https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/b-l475e-iot01a.html) based on WiFi connectivity.

That can be a good starting point if you build it and review the codebase.
However if you want to use a different STM32 family then you will need to port the project to your specific hardware.
Also if you have a different WiFi module, you will need to rewrite the drivers to fit to your hardware configuration. (You can only use a WiFi module which supports TLS connectivity, as that is mandatory for the AWS IoT Broker connection).

Another approach: in the AWS console under IoT Core > Device Software > FreeRTOS Device Software (https://eu-west-1.console.aws.amazon.com/iot/home?region=eu-west-1#/software/freertos) there are preconfigured packs for download. Alternatively you can also customize a device pack for download. You will be able to find the same device (STM32L475 Disco board) listed there.